# Retrieving a username that matches category name

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on a site that is using WooCommerce and also uses a plugin called User profiles made easy. The plugin displays the profiles of certain users.

Now the categories are named after the users of the site and what I would like to do is display the user who owns that category's profile at the top of the category page. I can only use user ID so I am having to extract the username from the ID.

What I have so far is:

```
<?php 
$username = get_categories();
if ( username_exists( $username ) )
{           
$user = get_userdatabylogin('$username');
var_dump($user);

echo do_shortcode("[upme 

username='.$user->ID.']"); }?>
```

This is to get the category name and check if there is a user with that name then show their profile.

Of course, it doesn't work so if anyone else knows where to go from here, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this code:

please follow the necessary arguments given below, remove unnecessary.

```
<?php 
$args = array(
    'type'                     => 'post',
    'child_of'                 => 0,
    'parent'                   => '',
    'orderby'                  => 'name',
    'order'                    => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty'               => 1,
    'hierarchical'             => 1,
    'exclude'                  => '',
    'include'                  => '',
    'number'                   => '',
    'taxonomy'                 => 'category',
    'pad_counts'               => false 

); 
$usernames = get_categories( $args );
foreach ( $usernames as $username ) {
    $userid = username_exists( $username );
        if($userid){
        $user = get_userdatabylogin('$username');
        var_dump($user);
        echo do_shortcode("[upme 
        username='.$user->ID.']");
   }
}

?>
```